# codeigniter cannot return several values instead of the whole row(from model to controller)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use codeigniter and I want to return from model to controller the following variables only  $a, $b, $c, $d  instead of the whole row but I am not sure if I wrote the code correctly. Could you please have a look at it.

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1){

            $row= $query->row_array(); 
            $a = $row['a'];
            $b= $row['b'];
            $c= $row['c'];
            $d= $row['d'];            

    return $query->result(); // return $row[]; ???

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below

```
$row = $query->row();
return array('a' => $row->a, 'b' => $row->b, 'c' => $row->c, 'd' => $row->d);
//$row->a, here a is column name of DB table
```